# ($prefix) in git config documentation

Tags: git, git-config

I quote:

[git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

**"--system
For writing options: write to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than the repository .git/config."**

Where and how is this `$(prefix)` variable set ?

On my mac this is: `/usr/local/git`

Update:

Based on 0x5453's answer I was able to find the ${PREFIX} from the Makefile here:

[Makefile](https://github.com/timcharper/git_osx_installer/blob/36c283e844cdcc1293983df635d0164cde010c2a/Makefile)

But is there a way to query it from the command line after installing git ?

Comment: This happens when git is built.  If you build manually from source you have the option to specify `--prefix` during configuration.

Comment: @0x5453 Is there a way for me to query what my $prefix is if lets say I install git from `https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/`

Comment: 0x5453 Please see update to question.

Comment: say `type git`.  The prefix is everything before `/bin/git`